# “relate better” vs. “better relate”

Tags: meaning, phonology, adverb-position

Please help settle a dispute (in my head).  Which of the following phrases works better?  Disregard the old "no split infinitives" rule. If either phrase is considered correct, which phrase rolls off the tongue more comfortably? Say it aloud, and share your opinion.

> 1. It will teach him to *relate better* to this community.
> 2. It will teach him to *better relate* to this community.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Why do you suppose one or the other is *not* correct? If this is regarding the old warning against "split infinitive," know that there is [no real grammatical justification](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/words/split-infinitives) for it. Please [edit](http://english.stackexchange.com/posts/274462/edit) your post to summarize the arguments being made, and what research you have attempted. I urge you to take the [site tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and review the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for additional guidance.

Comment: Of course, I invite Mr Hitchcock to rollback my edit if he finds my intervention so annoying. But first, I'd like to mention that I intervened when I saw the OP received an anoymous downvote. I upvoted to balance things out.

Comment: What is "trolling"? Something to do with fishing, right? Anyway, I really should have been more sensitive to your headache, and less concerned with helping the OP make sense of your oblique comment.

Comment: FYI the use of CAPS is generally frowned upon on EL&U but also elsewhere on the net. It is considered rude and similar to shouting. When first-comers submit their questions in CAPS they might get a hard deal from the community. If the OP looks through the archives, the number of questions in all CAPS is practically non-existent.

Answer (score 0):

> Better relate

Would be my choice. You could expand this to

> It will teach him to have a better relationship to this community

However the first form wouldn't support this expansion.